# Evaluating a definite integral with a complex constant

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I encounter this integral when considering emitter-photon scattering problems with unusual dispersion relations $E(k)=|k|^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha>1$.

*Suppose $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$, the integral I want to evaluate is
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty}dk \frac{1}{\exp(i\theta)-k^{\alpha}}.
\end{equation}
I am especially interested in the $\theta$ dependence of the integral.*

The following is my limited understanding of a similar problem, where   the integration range is $(-\infty, +\infty)$ instead:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dk \frac{1}{\exp(i\theta)-k^{\alpha}}.
\end{equation}
We consider rational $\alpha=p/q$, where integers $p,q$ do not have common factors, and when $p$ is odd, $q$ is also odd. Under these conditions, $k^\alpha$ is a real number for $k\in (-\infty,+\infty)$. For this modified integral, I can close the integration contour with a large semicircle linking $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, and apply the Cauchy Residue theorem to compute the integral. Since $\alpha$ is a rational number, the integrand has a finite number of poles and the evaluation is straightforward.

When the integration range is $(0, +\infty)$ (my original question), I do not know whether there is a way to close the contour such that I can still use the Cauchy Residue Theorem. And I also do not know how to consider the case when $\alpha$ is irrational.

Comment: Why do you believe that a closed form solution exists?